# Print output of an imported module

Tags: terraform

I want to run a debug session and since `terraform` does not have any functionality about viewing variable values when performing a `plan`, I am doing the following

```
locals {
  policy = flatten([
    for policy_name, policy_content in var.policy : [
      for content in policy_content : [
        for item in content : {
          name = policy_name
          capabilities = item
          path = item
        }
      ]
    ]
  ])
}
```

and

```
output "debug" {
  value       = local.policy
}
```

From the calling module:

```
module "policies" {
  source = "./path/to/module/above"

  for_each = var.policies
 
  policy = each.value

}

output "debug" {
  description = "Debug output"
  value       = module.policies[*].outputs.debug
}
```

This fails as follows:

```
│   on outputs.tf line 13, in output "debug":
│   13:   value       = module.policies[*].outputs.debug
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "outputs".
```

How can I work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either output everything from `policies`:

```
output "debug" {
  description = "Debug output"
  value       = module.policies
}
```

Or, use [`values()`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values) function to convert your `policies` map generated by [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) to a list, to which you can apply your [splat](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat) expression

```
output "debug" {
  description = "Debug output"
  value       = values(module.policies)[*].debug
}
```